# coordinate discrepancy when publishing from foursquare to twitter

Tags: twitter, foursquare

I'm working with a combination of twitter data (sourced via the user timeline api endpoint) and foursquare data (via the venue api endpoint) and I'm seeing some discrepancies between the venue coordinates in foursquare (response->venue->location->lat/lng) and the coordinates returned in the "coordinates" property of a tweet (sourced from foursquare).

For example in looking at a venue in the api explorer
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/4c1e4d1ec09ed13a66f8828e

I see latitude and longitude values of 38.506721964840004 and -90.33079780133309 respectively.

In a tweet sourced from foursquare referencing the URL to this same venue, the "coordinates" property is listed as 38.50676845, -90.33067839

While this is not a huge difference, it could be around 11m (depending on latitude). I doubt it is rounding error since it isn't only the last digits that are different.

Any insight on this?  Could one be the location of the individual when they check-in, and the other be the actual venue location?

Thanks.

Comment: How much time elapsed between the tweet's publishing and your retrieval of the venue's location from the foursquare API?

Comment: Looks like around a month difference in this instance.  This is not a unique case though.  I've seen this for a number of locations.  Do you know if foursquare updates the venue coordinates regularly?

Answer (score 0):

Venue coordinates are constantly being updated as Foursquare gathers more information and updates the location model for that each venue.

In addition to these incremental changes, venue managers and many super users have the ability to directly edit the lat/lng of a venue if incorrect.

Comment: Great.  Thanks very much for the feedback.  I'm assuming then that there is no way of accessing the actual location of the user when they check-in? I'm primarily interested in this for research purposes, understanding the spatial (polygonal) extent of check-ins and their relationship to the category of venue.

Comment: That is correct -- we don't release the phone's coordinates when a user checks in.